# __RequestVerificationToken always the same when reloading form in MVC4 application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

While on a development server a standard MVC4 / EF4.5 login form with Html.AntiForgeryToken() refreshes its value with every page load. When deploying the same code on IIS the hidden value __RequestVerificationToken is always the same (at least in one browser session). Other similar applications on the same server do not seem to have this behavior.

Which web.config/IIS parameter might be responsible for this?

Already tried setting the machine key (single server) but this only seems to shorten the token, the refresh problem remains the same.

Also tested in different browsers. Here are some demo values for IIS and development server:

IIS:

- Without machine key in web.config:

  `BGxqV7DjpHomi22By0r70WebHiWMV2OcsrCMN-dNDkRElZrv6BMQH23_zK9abmRsty_n1NImH2-gEsi3nBrWIQ2`
- With machine key in web.config:

  `dXBdht7mn2plT2rPvv0HzWtFvn-N9MT6xzW_xc8dVqnLdofzrL5v0SZFMAFPTANR0`

Cassini / development:

- Without machine key in web.config:

  `Yedkrxms9oYmHGzhV93qsrryVuNKZSWKBwCkP-RzK-tAZGgQ6J5g6Yp0LsCQPehucVwDcUs5lfRUf6Y6FxYUqY0olkE3-PmtF0ZnrCcbXD6XuA1PgPoFchreTPnCCSCwsh3E3FPmdKPlabyOfqiykkVqocxzYBMqd7A3bCZIxU01`
- With machine key in web.config:

  `iFjqi1OYplYfhCYdflAw1LSncVwK3b1yfDaJRgfrqVamucJ992D3-pFD__RolMZ_edp6muXQWLkxGOQp5Wn2ObTKXltO2J9tq32-JUMGu7cXdYZMkty3MRwuE-SuIFt7zo7TvQ2`

Comment: Html.AntiForgeryToken() refreshes per session. New session - new token.

Comment: Thanks, but does this explain that hitting F5 in development environment changes the hidden form value while doing exactly the same on the production server maintains the same hidden value in every page load (tested for example for Account/Login)? The cookie value is always the same in both environments (during one unauthenticated browser session), but I think the form value should randomize for every page load (as happens in other applications and on in development environment).

Comment: Anyone? When doing a WAS scan of the site this behavior seems to raise a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) issue in the affected forms

Answer (score 0):

Try the fix mentioned in the below KB. It solved the issue in our environment.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2656351